# verify request from cURL

Tags: php, function, curl, verification

I Have my script posting some data to a new site(server) using cURL, but I would like a way for my second script(server) to verify the server posting the data. Something like:

```
 If (in_array('sending_server', $array)) {
     /* continue the script */
 } else {
     die()
 }
```

For example I have this function checking wether or not the request is made using AJAX

```
 function is_ajax() {

     // BOOLEAN return if AJAX
     return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';

 }
```

But I don't know how to write the function for checking the server. does anybody know how to write it or know where I can find something helpful and similar?

Comment: why not generate a random number/string and send it with the request then you'll verify that when you receive a request.

Comment: @slash197 is right.. you can even sent a custom HEADER to the server and catch it like: `$_SERVER['HTTP_YOUR_HEADER_NAME']`

Comment: That is basically what I am doing now.. But didn't think that was secure enough..

Comment: So I set something like this `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('headerA: HeaderValue'));` and then check it like this: `$_SERVER['headerA']`?